# How to pass class type as an parameter to function?

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism

I have four classes: A, B, C, D.
B, C, D extends A.
I have a list - `List<A>` that contains all kinds of objects, and I want to build a function that gets one of the classes as parameter and prints from the list all the objects that belongs to the class.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.  Provide a [mre] of  how you expect this to work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```java
List<A> list = (...);

public static void print(Class klass) {
  for(A a : list) {
    if(klass.isInstance(a)) {
      System.out.println(a);
    }
  }
}
```

To use it:

```java
print(C.class);
```

Or

```java
C c = new C();

print(c.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void printElements(List<A> list, Class<? extends A> type) {
        for (A element : list) {
            if (type.isAssignableFrom(element.getClass())) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

The method `isAssignableFrom` can be used to determine if the Class received as a parameter is the same class or a superclass of each element of the list.

The `Class<? extends A>` is used to only allow types that are of type A or a subclass that are the type of elements allowed in the list.